# how to set loop value to textfield?

Tags: java, swing, loops, netbeans, textfield

when i use swing in netbeans

```
    Random acak = new Random ();
    int max = 99;
    int []hasilRandom = new int[9];
    for (int i = 0; i <hasilRandom.length; i++){
        hasilRandom[i] = acak.nextInt(max);
        jTextRandom.setText(hasilRandom[i]+", ");
    }
```

output : `48,`

what i want is like when i didnt use swing

```
    Random acak = new Random ();
    int max = 99;
    int []hasilRandom = new int[9];
    for (int i = 0; i <hasilRandom.length; i++){
        hasilRandom[i] = acak.nextInt(max);
        System.out.print(hasilRandom[i]+", ");
    }
```

output:`48, 30, 98, 78, 70, 16, 40, 2, 7,`

Sorry for my grammar, i hope u all understand.. :D

Comment: NetBeans is an IDE, not a programming language, edit your title accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Random acak = new Random ();
int max = 99;
int []hasilRandom = new int[9];
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i <hasilRandom.length; i++){
    hasilRandom[i] = acak.nextInt(max);
    text.append(hasilRandom[i]+", ");
}
jTextRandom.setText(text.toString());
```

You just overwrited text in textfield every time

Answer (score 0):

Just get the current text and append it like this instead of overwriting what is there already:

```
Random acak = new Random ();
int max = 99;
int []hasilRandom = new int[9];
for (int i = 0; i <hasilRandom.length; i++){
    hasilRandom[i] = acak.nextInt(max);
    jTextRandom.setText(jTextRandom.getText() + ", " + hasilRandom[i]); //use getText to append new value to current value
}
```